# CS50 Week1: credit task improvements?

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

First up: i got no prior coding experience and took nearly the whole day to do this task with only the tools they gave us in the first week.

I actually managed to do it, but the code looks not pretty and i want to see if i can improve it somehow?
How could i make the Luhn-algorithm more elegant or the boolean logic at the end (see the Mastercard OR orgy) ?

I would appreciate any help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    long num = get_long("Number: ");
    int sum_eo, sum_no;

    // determine length of input
    int length = 0; 
    for (long i = 1; i < num; i *= 10)
    {
        length++;
    }

    // determine the first two numbers of the input
    long start_digits = num;
    for (int i = 0; i < (length - 2); i++)
        {
            start_digits /= 10;
        }

    // Luhn-algorithm
    // first every other number from the back
    for (long i = 100; i < (num * 10); i = i*100)
    {
        int every_other = (((num % i)- (num % (i / 10))) / (i/10));
            if ((every_other * 2) < 10)
            {
                sum_eo = sum_eo + (every_other * 2);
             }
            else
            {
                 sum_eo = sum_eo + 1 + ((every_other*2) % 10);
             }
    }
    // then the other numbers
    for (long i = 10; i < (num * 10); i = i*100)
    {
        int every_no = (((num % i)- (num % (i / 10))) / (i/10));
        sum_no = sum_no + every_no;
    }

    //calculate checksum and choose which card
    int checksum = (sum_eo + sum_no) % 10;
    if (checksum == 0) // 
    {
        if (length == 15 && (start_digits == 34 || start_digits == 37))
        {
            printf("AMEX\n");
        }
        else if ((length == 13 || length == 16) && (start_digits / 10) == 4)
        {
            printf("VISA\n");
        }
        else if (length == 16 && (start_digits == 51 || start_digits == 52 || start_digits == 53 || start_digits == 54 || start_digits == 55))
        {
            printf("MASTERCARD\n");
        }
        else
            printf("INVALID\n");
    }
    else
        printf("INVALID\n");

}
```

Comment: If the code is fully functional, consider posting at [codereview.se].

Comment: `int sum_eo` has not been initialised before `sum_eo = sum_eo + (every_other * 2);`. Please take notice of compiler warnings. Similarly with `sum_no` in C local variables *must be initialised*. Well done, but you are off the track using an integer for a card number: use a string.

Comment: This looks like something that would be better handled using an array of digits. Use n%10 to get the last digit and n /= 10 to remove the last digit. Or use sprintf to create a string representation that is easy to convert to an array of digits.

Comment: @Han-Kwang Nienhuys the input can go *directly* to an array of digits: a string, without being converted to an integer, and back to form it was entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential change that you can make is here:

```
    else if (length == 16 && (start_digits == 51 || start_digits == 52 || start_digits == 53 || start_digits == 54 || start_digits == 55))
```

you can instead do this:

```
    else if (length == 16 && (start_digits >= 51 && start_digits <= 55))
```